# Can't connect from Windows 10 to Mac Mini using SMB

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, mac, smb

I have a Mac Mini running OS X 10.11 where I set up SMB to share a set of files with my Windows machine (I have Windows as the client, connecting to the Mac). I used to use Windows 7 and everything worked perfectly; now I have upgraded to Windows 10 (the 1803 version) and it doesn't connect anymore.

After searching around, I configured Windows 10 to use only NTLM2 when authenticating (as per https://www.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/3r5q16/cant_access_my_mac_from_windows_10/cwlohrv), but it still didn't work.

What happens is:

1. I click the "Connect to network share" option in Windows 10.
2. I type in the Mac's address, using the IP address to make sure it connects regardless of naming problems: `\\192.168.1.xxx\(share name)`. I also use *"connect using other credentials"*.
3. Windows asks me for username and password. I type them in. Windows asks me again. I type them in again.
4. Windows fails with an error code: `0x8007035 The Network path not found`.

I enabled SMB logging in the Mac, and this is what I get when Windows connects:

```
 digest-service[531]: label: default
 digest-service[531]:  dbname: od:/Local/Default
 digest-service[531]:  mkey_file: /var/db/krb5kdc/m-key
 digest-service[531]:  acl_file: /var/db/krb5kdc/kadmind.acl
 digest-service[531]: digest-request: uid=0
 digest-service[531]: digest-request: netr probe 0
 digest-service[531]: digest-request: init request
 digest-service[531]: digest-request: init return domain: MACMINI-DE32AE server: MEGA-MEDIA-CENTER indomain was: <NULL>
 digest-service[531]: digest-request: uid=0
 digest-service[531]: digest-request: init request
 digest-service[531]: digest-request: init return domain: MACMINI-DE32AE server: MEGA-MEDIA-CENTER indomain was: <NULL>
 digest-service[531]: digest-request: uid=0
 digest-service[531]: digest-request: init request
 digest-service[531]: digest-request: init return domain: MACMINI-DE32AE server: MEGA-MEDIA-CENTER indomain was: <NULL>
 digest-service[531]: digest-request: uid=0
 digest-service[531]: digest-request: init request
 digest-service[531]: digest-request: init return domain: MACMINI-DE32AE server: MEGA-MEDIA-CENTER indomain was: <NULL>
 digest-service[531]: digest-request: uid=0
 digest-service[531]: digest-request: od failed with -1561745588 proto=ntlmv2
 digest-service[531]: digest-request: user=BIGBRAIN4\Paulo
 digest-service[531]: digest-request kdc: ok user=MACMINI-DE32AE\Paulo proto=ntlmv2 flags: NEG_KEYEX, ENC_128, NEG_VERSION, NEG_TARGET_INFO, NEG_NTLM2, NEG_ALWAYS_SIGN, NEG_NTLM, NEG_SIGN, NEG_TARGET, NEG_UNICODE
```

So... what's going on? As I said, everything worked perfectly with Windows 7, and I haven't touched anything in the Mac's setup since then.

Comment: idk if this is any use, mainly it discusses what you already tried, NTLM2 only - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152900/share-mac-files-yosemite-with-windows/152906#152906

Comment: @Tetsujin: thanks. As mentioned, I already changed that in my Windows 10 machine.

Comment: Try using the "net use" DOS command.  You can pass in the credentials on the command-line (yeah yeah, not secure if someone else is logged into your PC and can see your Task Mgr).  When I've had strange (Windows-to-Windows) fileshare access problems, this has always helped.  That said, I've been unable to connect my PC and my Mac since Windows 8, so something else really changed besides NTLM, which shouldn't come into play with a Mac fileshare.